# Kotlin - List of Object Filter

Tags: kotlin, filter

I have a list of nested objects I want a logic to filter the list.
Theater, Screen, Show, Movie are data classes.

```
Theater(
    theaterId = 1, name = "Inox", screen = listOf(
        Screen(id = 1, showList = listOf(
            Show(1, "9 AM", movieId = 1,160) ,
            Show(2, "12 PM", movieId = 2,200),
            Show(3, "3 PM", movieId = 3,240)
        )) ,
        Screen(id = 2, showList = listOf(
            Show(1, "10 AM", movieId = 4,160),
            Show(2, "1 PM", movieId = 5,200),
            Show(3, "4 PM", movieId = 1,240)
        )))) , Theater(
    theaterId = 2, name = "PVR", screen = listOf(
        Screen(id = 1, showList = listOf(
            Show(1, "9 AM", movieId = 2,160),
            Show(2, "12 PM", movieId = 3,200),
            Show(3, "3 PM", movieId = 4,240)
        )),
        Screen(id = 2, showList = listOf(
            Show(1, "10 AM", movieId = 5,160),
            Show(2, "1 PM", movieId = 1,200),
            Show(3, "4 PM", movieId = 2,240)
        ))))
```

The expected list after passing a movieId. = 1 should be like .

```
Theater(
    theaterId = 1, name = "Inox", screen = listOf(
        Screen(id = 1, showList = listOf(
            Show(1, "9 AM", movieId = 1,160) ,
        )) ,
        Screen(id = 2, showList = listOf(
            Show(3, "4 PM", movieId = 1,240)
        )))) , Theater(
    theaterId = 2, name = "PVR", screen = listOf(
        Screen(id = 1, showList = listOf(
        )),
        Screen(id = 2, showList = listOf(
            Show(2, "1 PM", movieId = 1,200),
        ))))
```

In the second theater there is no movie running in screen 1 so it should be empty.

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
val result = input.map { theater ->
    theater.copy(screen = theater.screen.map { screen ->
        screen.copy(showList = screen.showList.filter { it.movieId == 1 })
    })
}
```

https://pl.kotl.in/duRIOgCV7

Comment: Hi can you please explain the logic a bit.

Comment: Data classes are immutable (as well as all their properties in this case), so to tweak some of their properties we have to recreate them with the desired value for the respectful properties. Luckily, there is a [`copy` method](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html#copying) in data classes for it. So, after filtering `showList` by `movieId` of its items, we need to recreate `screen` with a new value for `showList` property (passing there this filtering result), and then recreate `theater` with the list of this newly created `screen`s.

Comment: To learn how `map` and `filter` methods work see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-transformations.html#map and https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-filtering.html